# Group by - Dataframe with lists

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help with Pandas..

I have a Dataframe which I want to group by the ID column (that works so far). The Tags column can contain lists with different amounts Elements and also empty lists.

```
g = data_lemmatized.groupby('ID')['Tags'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x)))
```

This is the original dataframe:

[image]

With the code I used, I'm recieving the following result:

[image]

What I would like to have in the new dataframe is:

-a single list with no sub-lists inside, just with the elements or empty

-no duplicates within the lists (a set of each grouped list)

Example:

```
0 -> []
1 -> []
2 -> [DTU]
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: can you post a sample of `data_lemmatized` ? just 5 rows will do.

Comment: added another screenshot

Comment: we need a [mcve] not screengrabs, i can't paste your screengrab into my IDE :)

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '7', '8', '8'],
                   'Tags': [[], [], ['DTV'], [], [], ['VOIVE_REC'], ['SCREEN'], [], ['PRESET'], [], ['PRESETSET'], [], [], ['VOICE_REC'], ['DTV'], ['VOICE_REC', 'PHONE_CONTACTS']]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
data_lemmatized = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                                "Tags": [[], [], ['DTU'], [], []]})

data_lemmatized.groupby('ID')['Tags'].sum().apply(set).apply(list)
```

Here, sum of list returns concatenation of lists.

Comment: In the ID col there is a jump from 334 to 336 since I removed 335 in another step. Now I get a NaN at ID 336 and all following values from Tags are moved by one row.. Any idea what the reason could be?